# Displaying all array elements on the screen, randomly, one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to the community and recently posted this question, but I was not detailed enough in my description to get the response I was looking for. Sorry. Thank you to everyone, though, who offered their help. What I have so far: I can create an array in which an element is randomly drawn and presented to the screen with a click of a button. And that element is then removed from the array Perfect! But the code I have only displays to the screen the element that is currently being sliced. What I am wanting to do is display each individual element to the screen, as it is randomly spliced, so that I end up with all elements on the screen and an empty array. I very unsuccessfully tried using a loop. Sorry for my lack clarity on my initial post and thanks in advance for the additional help.

```
function RandomDraw(){
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    var rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
    document.getElementById("showSplice").textContent = rs;
    document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray;
}
```

Comment: what are the items in myArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use innerHTML += instead of stamping out the existing value with textContent.  See [this code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdQrEe).

```
function RandomDraw(){
  var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  var rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
  document.getElementById("showSplice").innerHTML += rs;
  document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I was not expecting it to look so easy. Thanks for the lesson. -Don

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer that best-assisted your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you still want this on the click of a button because you say you're trying to use a loop, so I implemented a `setTimeout` to mimic what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

// Grab the elements outside of the function so you don't grab
// them each iteration
var showSplice = document.getElementById("showSplice");
var showArrayList = document.getElementById("showArrayList");

function loop(arr) {

  // If there are still elements in the array
  if (arr.length) {
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var rs = arr.splice(ri, 1);

    // If the array still has elements append the spliced element and
    // a comma to the textContent, otherwise just the spliced element
    showSplice.textContent += arr.length ? rs + ', ' : rs;
    showArrayList.innerHTML = arr;

    // Send the spliced array to loop again (1/2 second loop)
    setTimeout(loop, 500, arr);
  }
}

// Call loop with the array
loop(arr);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ndk72u34/8/)**

Comment: Not what I was looking for. But thank you for the lesson. That's something more for me to put under my hat.  -Don

Answer (score 1):

You could just append the text content, instead of overwriting it.

```
function RandomDraw(){
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    var rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
    document.getElementById("showSplice").textContent += ' ' + rs;
    document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray;
}
```

Comment: Sooo Cool! That works perfectly. I was expecting numerous lines of code to achieve this. I have a lot to learn. Thanks for the education. -Don

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray.join(', ');

function RandomDraw(){
    const ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    const rs = myArray.splice(ri, 1);
    const showSpliceElement = document.getElementById("showSplice");
    const splicedElements = showSpliceElement.innerHTML;
    showSpliceElement.innerHTML +=
      splicedElements && rs.length
        ? `, ${rs}`
        : rs;
    document.getElementById("showArrayList").innerHTML = myArray.join(', ');
}
```

```html
Splice: <span id="showSplice"></span><br>
Array: <span id="showArrayList"></span><br>
<button onclick="RandomDraw()">Go</button>
```